# How to get data from URI in js in a synchronous way

Tags: javascript, vue.js, uri

I'm trying to get data from a uri. I use the exemple at :
*https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1*
and try to display the id ("id" : "1").
I have to get this value into a variable because I'm also using vuejs template.

Is there a simple way to get a cute little data ?

I tried Promises, and XMLHttpRequest, but send() throws error "fs.writeFileSync is not a function", and I failed to synchronise Promises...

There is my code before the export for vuejs template :

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var fs = require('browserify-fs');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

/*function succes(msg){
  console.log('ok : '+msg);
  changeAffichage(msg);
}
function echec(msg){console.log('ko : '+msg); changeAffichage("error");}
function uri(){
  return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
    .then(function(response){
      return response.json()
      .then(function(value) {
        console.log('value : ');
        console.log(value);
        console.log('id = '+value.id);
        return value.id;
      }).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Il y a eu un problème avec l\'opération fetch: ' + error.message);
});
    }).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Il y a eu un problème avec l\'opération fetch: ' + error.message);
});
}*/
function changeAffichage(msg){
  window.affichage=msg;
  console.log("new affichage : "+window.affichage);
}
window.affichage="Meow";
//Promise.all([uri()]).then(succes, echec);

sleep(200);

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1', false);
xhr.send(null);
if (xhr.status === 200) {
    console.log("Réponse reçue: %s", xhr.responseText);
} else {
    console.log("Status de la réponse: %d (%s)", xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
}
changeAffichage(xhr.responseText);

console.log('affichage final = ' + window.affichage);
```

I want to get the value of id into window.affichage, please :(

Comment: Could you explain what's the vue tag used for here? It seems like plain JS to me right now.

Comment: I use vuejs tag because it's a big constraint for me. I use a vuejs template but don't understand it so I can't use complicated things, and have only one <script></script> available

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is the purpose with Vue here, but you if you want to make an http request you can do it with vue-axios package and assign the result of your http request to reactive property

Comment: We asked me to use this vuejs template, even if I never heard about vuejs.
I found where to put my value to display it, but it's in the middle of an array of values so I will not put my request next to the value ^^

Answer (score 0):

So, I found how to do :

```
var request = require('sync-request');
var res = request('POST', 'http://MyAPIIP/connect?mail='+this.model.email+'&pass='+this.model.password);
reponse = String(JSON.parse(res.body)[0]['rep']);
console.log(reponse);
```